# MS Access SQL: Sum IIF for multiple Criteria, Format as Column instead of Row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working in MS Access 365 and I have a table containing multiple status that I want to summarize in a Pie Chart.

Sample Data:

| Sales Order# | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New |
| 2 | Pending |
| 3 | Closed |

The Statuses are defined by human readable text in a separate table, but are linked in the master table before I run the query. I have the following query to create a summary of each status in the Table.

```
SELECT 
     Sum(IIf(Table.Status=1,1,0)) AS ["New"], 
     Sum(IIf(Table.Status=2,1,0)) AS ["Pending"], 
     Sum(IIf(Table.Status=3,1,0)) AS ["Closed"], 
FROM Table;
```

The issue is that this formats the query result as:

| New | Pending | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

And due to the insane rules around MS Access charting, a Pie chart bases the data off of the 1st two columns and not anything else. How can I reformat my results to be in a column format to make the charting work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is the hard way. Why not count by grouping?

```
SELECT status, count(status) 
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY status;
```

I don't have MS Access on my Android phone, so I can't show the output.

The previous query gives counts on the ID, for the names, since you mentioned `StatusName` could be:

```
SELECT StatusName, count(StatusName) 
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY StatusName;
```

That assumes a join is not needed to some other `Table` to resolve the counts.

Comment: Hah, yes I reached that conclusion shortly after posting it, now the only issue is I cant get the chart to display the actual text based Status names instead of the code. Since the way this DB is built, the Codes (1,2,3) are tied to the statuses (New, Pending, Closed) on the DB back end.

The results of the query display the correct text values, but the chart just displays 1,2,3,etc...

Comment: So what is the column name that has the status text? ... The query can easily be modified.

Comment: Table.Status stores a number which matches TblStatus.StatusID and then displays TblStatus.StatusName. The issue is even though the above query correctly returns:

New - 2
Pending - 1
Closed - 1

etc... the chart, only displays the ID numbers. Not sure if that's a consequence of Access's crappy charting or something I'm doing wrong on the SQL end.

Comment: I updated the answer with counts based on the name too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for three rows with two columns?

```
SELECT SWITCH(Table.Status = 1, "New",
              Table.Status = 2, "Pending",
              Table.Status = 3, "Closed",
              1=1, "Other"
             ) as status,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY SWITCH(Table.Status = 1, "New",
                Table.Status = 2, "Pending",
                Table.Status = 3, "Closed",
                1=1, "Other"
               );
```